# NameError: name "webdriver" is not defined

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have create a python script which requires the webdrive. In my code I have imported it like so, `from selenium import webdriver`.

I went to their website [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium#downloads) downloaded and ran setup.py but still does not import it. I don't know if this helps but I have python 2.7, I also do not have installed pip.

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to coding and python as a whole but I was able to figure it out. At least what was giving me trouble.

in console: `import selenium`

`from selenium import webdriver`

then I was able to run: `driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')`

chrome driver opened.

Answer (score 3):

This means that you have installed `selenium` package somewhere on your system, but the interpreter can not find it, either in the standard location, or the `pythonpath` override. Please try this in `ipython` or in `Python2.7` shell:

```
import selenium
selenium.__file__
```

The above command statements should print out the path to the exact `selenium` folder that you import. If it not located in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` (default Windows path for new package installation) then delete it or rename (if you don't really need it).
Or just download `selenium` from another source that installs it to the standard location.

Comment: Example: `$ python -c "import selenium; print(selenium.__file__)"` returned
`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/__init__.py`

Answer (score 2):

After you get the path to the driver, for instance, you can open Chrome via:

```
from selenium import webdriver
    
path = "C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```